# Calling OpeCL.dll API works from one project but not from another in same solution

Tags: .net, opencl, .net-6.0, dllimport, .net-standard

I'm trying to use this nice OpenCL API library wrapper to work on neural nets with dotnet.
https://github.com/lecode-official/opencl-dotnet

The dotnet library projects in the repo are dotnet standard 2.1, and the OpenCl.DotNetCore.Tests console app is dotnet core 2.1.

Running the test console app that's included in the repo works perfectly fine. However, if I create a dotnet 6.0 console app in the same solution with the following main function

```
static async Task Main(string[] args)
{ 
    Console.WriteLine("Starting test!");
    IEnumerable<Platform> platforms = Platform.GetPlatforms().ToList();
}
```

I get the exception
**System.EntryPointNotFoundException: 'Unable to find an entry point named 'clGetPlatformIDs' in DLL 'OpenCL'.'**

Why does calling the OpenCL.dll work from one project but not from the other one?

The repo's test console app runs fine even if I change its target framework to dotnet 6.0.

Without success I've also tried to:

- Paste all the code related to GetPlatform() to the current console app project I'm trying to get working.
- Have a one second delay between the GetPlatform() and ToList() call, since without ToList() the Main runs succesfully. The ToList() can also be changed to foreaching the platforms and it also throws the same exception.
- Use the exact same Main function as above (with ToList()) in the repo's project and it works fine.
- Copy OpenCL.dll to the solution folder or the bin folder where the console app's exe is.

I cannot find any meaningful differences between my console app project and the OpenCl.DotNetCore.Tests project if I change its target platform to dotnet 6.0.

Answer (score 0):

The problem was that I had my own dotnet project named "OpenCL" in my solution. Obviously the dotnet 6.0 console app was trying to find the entrypoint in it without success. I figured this out by adding dependencies to my projects from the working console app and then it failing.

Moral of the story, given this error, **make sure that you do not have name collisions with the external library you are trying to use.**